# Setup VirtualHost to connect only via OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

My setup is as follows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet
          inet addr:10.10.20.20
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
tun0      inet addr:10.8.0.1
```

I would like to set my webmail to be accessible only when connecting via
VPN.  Currently, the VirtualHost directive is *:443.  I assume I want to
replace the * with the eth1 address.

But do I also have to set an iptables route?  If so, what/how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the OpenVPN server, add a below line:

```
push "route web.mail.ip.address"
```

In virtual host section, you can restrict access based on IP address, something like this:

```
<Directory "/your/virtual/host/directory">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from vpn.server.ip.address
    ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added : push "route web.mail.ip.address" with web.mail.ip.address as the external IP address of the server.  For the "vpn.server.ip.address", I have tried 127.0.0.1, the external address, and the VPN subnet, but I always get sent to the ErrorDocument.  What should I be using for this value?

Comment: Looking at the logs, it says: "[client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration:" where the IP address there is the public IP address of my laptop's connection.  Even though I am VPN'd in (whatusmyip.com shows an IP of the server, and I am connected to the VPN server).

Comment: Check your routing table `route -n`. Make sure that you have a static route to web mail via `tun0` interface.

Comment: `Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface`
`10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0`

Comment: So there seems to be something wrong with the way I created the route.

Comment: What is the web mail's IP address and VPN server? You should edit your original post and append the routing table to keep formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.180.160.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

The webmail's IP address is the same as my server, let's say X.X.X.X.

The VPN server is on the same machine, and has a config file that has:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

When I added:
    push "route X.X.X.X"

I couldn't get to the webmail address.

The weird thing is that even when I was connected to the VPN, and my IP address from http://www.whatismyip.com showed my server's IP address, the webmail logs showed that I was trying to connect from my ISP's IP address.